# How can I do a live-updating web page without server-side scripting access?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have an off-the-shelf embedded Ethernet module which monitors an external electronic system. This Ethernet module includes a very limited web server. This web server does not support *any* sort of standard scripting language. To read the status of the system being monitored, I can embed very specific commands into the comments of the HTML file. When the file is served, the server knows to replace those comments with the requested data. In this way, I can view via my browser the status of the system.

My problem is this: the server will ONLY supply updated data when it serves an HTML page. There is no way to do an asynchronous request. This makes live data essentially impossible; to get updated information on the status of the system, I have to refresh the entire page. That's slow, inefficient, and ugly. I'd like to find a way to have my status page update live.

I suspect this will require me to use Javascript to asynchronously request a second HTML page containing all the interesting data, then parse that file and use the data to update the main page, all without actually refreshing the page I'm looking at. I have no idea how to go about this, or if it's even possible. Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using XMLHttpRequest, as long as both HTML files will be stored in the same location (to avoid CORS constraints).

Have a look at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for examples on how to use XMLHttpRequest.

The high-level view would be:

```
// live webpage
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () { /* parse xhr.repsonseText */ };
xhr.onerror = function () { /* ... */ };

xhr.open('get', 'server-updated-page.html', true);
xhr.send();
```